# Can't submit app for review through xcode 8

Tags: app-store, xcode8

I got the following error message when I tried to submit my application to App Store.

[image]

But I'm using Official release of Xcode 8.

[image]

My OS is also not beta version.

[image]

What is the cause for this? Thanks.

Comment: I uninstall my Xcode 8 and reinstall it through App Store again. But the problem still there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's an iOS app, please check the Info.plist of your IPA's App Bundle. Unzip the IPA, open Payload/*.app/Info.plist, look for `<key>DTXcodeBuild</key>`, it should say `<string>8A218a</string>`. If not, the app was build with a previous / another version of Xcode.

You should also be sure to use the newest Application Loader for uploading your app: Right-Click on Xcode -> Open Developer Tool -> Application Loader.

Comment: Mine is `<string>8A218a</string>`. I uploaded through Organizer.

Comment: I got this error when I tried to submit through Application Loader: `"Beta Toolchain. This app has been built using beta toolchains. Apps built with beta toolchains are acceptable for TestFlight submission. Note that you will not be able to submit these builds for sale on the App Store."`

Comment: Okay can you also check the keys <key>DTSDKBuild</key> (should be 14A345) and DTSDKName (should be iphoneos10.0).

Comment: And please be sure to use the default toolchain like described here https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/AlternativeToolchains.html

Comment: The <key>DTSDKBuild</key> is 14A345

Comment: I fixed the issue finally by change the value for key "BuildMachineOSBuild"  to "15F34" in info.plist of my archive. I accept your answer because it reminds me to check my info.plist. Anyway it means we should never install beta OS in the machine of development. This is actually quite weird. Don't understand why Apple doing this.